# Proving semiregularity of a topological space.

Tags: general-topology

I'm working in some exercise of the book *Extensions and Absolutes of Hausdorff Spaces* by Porter and Woods and I'm stucked in the proof. The exercise is $7$H(2):

> Let $X$ be a regular space, $Y$ a set and $f:X\to Y$ a compact, irreducible surjection. Prove that $\{f[A]\mid A \ \text{is closed in} \ X \}$ is a closed base for a semiregular Hausdorff topology on $Y$ and $f:X\to Y$ is a perfect, irreducible, $\theta$-continuous surjection. In particular, if $X$ is compact, show that $Y$ is minimal Hausdorff.

I'm almost done. The only thing that remains is to prove that $Y$ is semiregular. My full atempt:

First, is clear that $\mathcal{H}=\{f[A]\mid A \ \text{is closed in} \ X \}$ is a closed base because

1. $\bigcap\mathcal{H}=\emptyset$ since $\emptyset$ is a closed subset of $X$ and $f[\emptyset]=\emptyset$. Then $\emptyset\in\mathcal{H}$.
2. Clearly $\mathcal{H}$ is closed under finite unions and therefore, given $x\notin f[A_1]\cup f[A_2]$ with $f[A_1], f[A_2]\in\mathcal{H}$, then $x\notin f[A_1\cup A_2]$ and $f[A_1\cup A_2]\in\mathcal{H}$. (following [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#:%7E:text=Given%20a%20topological%20space%20X,A%20but%20not%20containing%20x.) definition)

Therefore $\mathcal{H}$ is a closed base. Now take $y_1,y_2\in Y$ with $y_1\neq y_2$. Then $f^{-1}[\{y_1 \}]\cap f^{-1}[\{y_2 \}]=\emptyset$ and, as $f$ is a function with compact fibers, then there exist $U$ and $V$ disjoint open sets such that $f^{-1}[\{y_1 \}]\subseteq U$ and $f^{-1}[\{y_2 \}]\subseteq V$. Then $Y\setminus f[X\setminus U]$ and $Y\setminus f[X\setminus V]$ are disjoint open sets and $y_1\in Y\setminus f[X\setminus U]$ and $y_2\in Y\setminus f[X\setminus V]$. Thus, $Y$ is Hausdorff. In order to prove the $\theta$-continuity, I found [this](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/projective-elements-in-categories-with-perfect-continuous-maps/1272696B340714482C3EAD156A27F1AE) article and the proof is correct (with a little typos). Next, by hyphotesys $f$ is a surjective function with compact fibers and irreducible. Moreover, by definition of the topology of $Y$, $f$ is a closed function and therefore, $f$ is perfect, irreducible and $\theta$-continuous. Finally, the problem is to prove the semiregularity of $Y$. The book contains a hint.

> Use the next theorem to show that $Y$ is semiregular.
>
> 6.5(d) **Theorem**. Let $f$ be an irreducible $\theta$-continous function from $X$ onto $Y$. Then:
>
> 1. If $A$ and $B$ are closed subsets of $X$ such that $\operatorname{int}_{X}(A\cap B)=\emptyset$ then $\operatorname{int}_{Y}\left(f[A]\cap f[B] \right)=\emptyset$
> 2. If $C$ is a closed nowhere dense subset of $X$, then $f[C]$ is a closed nowhere dense subset of $Y$.
> 3. The map $A\to f[A]$ is a Boolean algebra isomorphism from $R(X)$ onto $R(Y)$ where $R(X)$ is the collection of all regular closed sets.
> 4. If $Y$ is extremally disconnected then $f$ is one-to-one; if $f$ is also continuous then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

I tried to use 6.5(d) 3 to prove the result. My attempt:

In order to prove that $Y$ is semiregular, is enough to prove that for every open basic set of $Y$, there exist a regular open set contained in it. Take $Y\setminus f[B]$ a basic open set and $z\in Y\setminus f[B]$. Then $f^{-1}[\{z \}]\cap B=\emptyset$. As $X$ is regular, there exist $U$ and $V$ disjoint open sets such that $f^{-1}[\{z \}]\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq V$. Again, by the regularity of $X$, we can take $W$ an open set such that $$f^{-1}[\{z \}]\subseteq W \subseteq\operatorname{cl}_{X}(W)\subseteq W$$All follows from the compactness of $f^{-1}[\{z \}]$. Then $$z\in f[W]\subseteq f[\operatorname{cl}_{X}(W)]\subseteq f[U]$$As $\operatorname{cl}_{X}(W)$ is a regular closed set in $X$, then, by 6.5(d) 3, $f[\operatorname{cl}_{X}(W)]$ is a regular closed set in $Y$. Here my idea is take $\operatorname{int}_{Y}\left( f[\operatorname{cl}_{X}(W)]\right)$. This is a regular open set but, is it true that $z\in \operatorname{int}_{Y}\left( f[\operatorname{cl}_{X}(W)]\right)$? And, is it true that $f[U]\subseteq Y\setminus f[B]$? Any suggestion? I appreciate any help. Thanks.

P.S.: if $X$ is compact then $X$ is $H$-closed and, by the $\theta$-continuity of $f$, follows that $f[X]=Y$ is $H$-closed. Moreover, by the previous argument (not proved yet), $Y$ is semiregular and $H$-closed + semiregular implies minimal Hausdorff. Thus $Y$ is minimal Hausdorff. Therefore, this argument proves the particular case given in the exercise. But, again, I need the semiregularity of $Y$.